# Python if any retruns wrong answer

Tags: python

I have a simple code that looks for any string from the list in another string using if any, but returns "False" even though it should return "True".
Where is the problem?

```py
a = "Little mushroom in the forest"
b = ["in the forest", "kick off", "ball"]

if any(word in b for word in a):
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Comment: Your condition backwards, I think you want `any(word in a for word in b)`

Comment: You are right, Cory. Now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right!

```
a = "Little mushroom in the forest" 
b = ["in the forest", "kick off", "ball"]

if any(word in a for word in b): 
    print("True") 
else: 
    print("False")
```

What `any(word in a for word in b)` does is that it iterates over the strings in b, and returns true if any of them is in a, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You had it reversed in your if statement. The code was checking if any letter in the string a was equal to one of the strings in the b array.
Try this:

```
    if any(word in a for word in b): 
        print("True") 
    else: 
        print("False")
```